# ListView swipe to delete

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to achieve that in NativeScript's ListView?
RadListView has this mechanism built in, but ListView has better performance for my layout.
I've been searching in the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listview) and it appeared that there isn't any, so I looked for a way to do it in the native elements: iOS's UITableView and Android's ListView-
For UITableView I found [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcells) blogpost that suggests that:

> It takes just one method to enable swipe to delete in table views:
>   tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)

So how do I translate this to NativeScript?
The swift code from the post is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

Also, is there a straightforward way to do that in Android's ListView?

Comment: https://github.com/tsonevn/ListViewEditable/blob/master/app/myds.ts could be useful.

Comment: @NarendraMongiya It is useful! thank you, Will get on to try and use it in Angular. Have you had a chance to do the same in Android?